# C++ Template Collection Type

Tags: c++, templates, vector, collections, std

Edit. Please see my comment.

I've been struggling with this for a while now.  I've been writing a mergesort routine that operates on vectors (reinventing the wheel admittedly), and I've been passing iterators to my sort function.  Within the sort function, I create a temporary vector.  Now, I'd like it to operate on any element type, as there's nothing in the code that is specific to ints/doubles etc etc.  I can't seem to get my template definition working.  I've tried many many different ways of doing this. If someone could possibly look at the small snippet I've written below, and show me how to get it working so that I can accept a vector::iterator as a function argument, and then declare and use a vector within the function itself, I'd really appreciate it.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void test(vector<T>::iterator myiter) {
  typename vector<T> myvec;
}
```

here's my compile time error:

```
$ make tmpl
g++  -Wall -ggdb --std=c++11   tmpl.cc   -o tmpl
tmpl.cc:5:22: error: variable or field ‘test’ declared void
 void test(vector<T>::iterator myiter) {
                      ^
tmpl.cc:5:31: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘myiter’
 void test(vector<T>::iterator myiter) {
```

If it's of any interest, this is a current snapshot of the full listing I'm working with - and merge() is the one I'm struggling with.  I've changed the template syntax multiple times with various types of fail:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Iter>
void print_collection(Iter start, Iter end) {
  std::cout << "collection = { ";
  for(; start != end; ++start) {
    std::cout << *start << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << "};" << std::endl;
}


template <typename T>
void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
  std::vector<T> temp;
  std::vector<T>::iterator i, j;
  i = start;
  j = pivot;
  while(i != pivot && j != end) {
    if(*i <= *j) {
      temp.push_back(*i);
      ++i;
    } else if(*i > *j) {
      temp.push_back(*j);
      ++j;
    }
  }
  for(; i != pivot; ++i) {
    temp.push_back(*i);
  }
  for(; j != end; ++j) {
    temp.push_back(*j);
  }
  i = start;
  j = temp.begin();
  for(; i != end, j != temp.end(); ++i, ++j) {
    *i = *j;
  }
}


template <typename Iter>
void merge_sort(Iter start, Iter end, int len) {
  if(len <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  int odd, left_len, right_len;
  Iter pivot;
  odd = len % 2;
  left_len = (len / 2) + odd;
  pivot = start + left_len;
  right_len = len / 2;

  merge_sort(start, pivot, left_len);
  merge_sort(pivot, end, right_len);
  merge(start, pivot, end, left_len, right_len);
}


int main(void) {
  std::vector<double> vl = { 1.1, 9.1, 2.1, 8.1, 3.1, 7.1, 4.1, 6.1, 5.1, 0.1 };
  print_collection(vl.begin(), vl.end());
  merge_sort(vl.begin(), vl.end(), vl.size());
  print_collection(vl.begin(), vl.end());
  return 0;
}
```

and here's the compile error from the full listing:

```
$ make vec
g++  -Wall -ggdb --std=c++11   vec.cc   -o vec
vec.cc:39:28: error: variable or field ‘merge’ declared void
 void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
                            ^
vec.cc:39:37: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘start’
 void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
                                     ^
vec.cc:39:69: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pivot’
 void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
                                                                     ^
vec.cc:39:101: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘end’
 void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
                                                                                                     ^
vec.cc:39:106: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
 void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
                                                                                                          ^
vec.cc:39:120: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
 void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
                                                                                                                        ^
vec.cc: In instantiation of ‘void merge_sort(Iter, Iter, int) [with Iter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >]’:
vec.cc:88:45:   required from here
vec.cc:81:47: error: ‘merge’ was not declared in this scope
   merge(start, pivot, end, left_len, right_len);
```

^

Comment: I've spent ages looking at the linked question which mine is supposedly a duplicate of. I spent a fair while trading it before deciding to ask my question  I think I've asked a very specific question and put a fair amount of work in to asking it succinctly, enough to justify it being seen as an entirely different question. I appreciate that i may be missing a fundamental point of templating and the linked answer is not helping me much.   I'm not that experienced with c++ and it'd be very much appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. All instances of `std::vector<T>::iterator` should be `typename std::vector<T>::iterator` since it's dependent on a template parameter. The reason is explained in the canonical question [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

   The error message here is much clearer if you [compile with Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83ee7a8e8d5d036d):

   ```
   main.cpp:15:12: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::vector<T>::iterator'
   void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              typename 
   main.cpp:15:44: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::vector<T>::iterator'
   void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                              typename 
   main.cpp:15:76: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::vector<T>::iterator'
   void merge(std::vector<T>::iterator start, std::vector<T>::iterator pivot, std::vector<T>::iterator end, int left_len, int right_len) {
                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                              typename 
   main.cpp:17:3: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::vector<T>::iterator'
     std::vector<T>::iterator i, j;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     typename
   ```
2. [Once you fix that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7fadbc25d5a9366), the compiler will tell you that it can't deduce `T` when `merge` is called, because everything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context. There is no real reason why `merge` should be templated on `T` and not the iterator type, or indeed why it must be limited to iterators into a `std::vector` (other than the one place in the code when you first assign `pivot` and then `temp.begin()` to `j`, which can be easily fixed by adding another variable) :

   ```
   template <typename Iter>
   void merge(Iter start, Iter pivot, Iter end, int left_len, int right_len);
   ```

   But you create a `std::vector<T>` as scratch, so we now need to figure out `T`, or the iterator's value type. The way to do it is via `std::iterator_traits`:

   ```
   typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type T;
   ```

Side issue: `i != end, j != temp.end()` as a loop condition makes little sense. Presumably you meant `i != end && j != temp.end()`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93b7e630ef7b9023).

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  It really is what I wanted.  Some might argue that it wasn't what I needed haha.  I did manage to get a little further and was coming back to post an update.  I think your comments really help to clarify my particular problem, and the iterator_traits tip is really helpful!  In case your interested, this is what I had come up with.  It functions, but there's a lot of baggage!   http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7fc65269ab56a8e